# UnsatisfiedLinkError when shared library is a used in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an NDK project in Android studio that adds and subtracts 2 numbers

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        JniAdapter jniAdapter = new JniAdapter();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Sum of 1 and 1 is: " + jniAdapter.add(1, 1));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Difference of 1 and 1 is: " + jniAdapter.subtract(1, 1));
    }
```

The addition operation is provided by an external **static** library and the subtraction by an external **shared** library, that were built with ol'school ndk-build; I want my gradle file to compile these two libraries and build another shared library. But it looks like the static library is being compiled in, but not the shared library and I get an UnSatifiedLinkErrorfor the shared library.Without the shared library everything works fine. Whats going wrong?

My gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        .....

        defaultConfig.with {
          .......
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native"
        ldLibs += ["mySharedLib"] 
        ldLibs += ["myStaticLib"]
        cppFlags += "-I${staticLibIncludeRoot}".toString() 
        cppFlags += "-I${sharedLibIncludeRoot}".toString()
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create ("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
            ndk.ldFlags += "-L${staticLibRoot}/armeabi-v7a".toString() 
            ndk.ldFlags += "-L${sharedLibRoot}/armeabi-v7a".toString()
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the nature of shared libraries. There is no conventional procedure to "compile", link or otherwise convert a shared library into a bigger one (some tools help to stripe or shrink a shared libraries, but this is a different story).

It is perfectly ok to use prebuilt shared libraries with Android Studio project, and deal with them through gradle.

The easiest way is to add the path to such shared libraries to `jniLibs.srcDirs`. The Android plugin will copy the relevant binaries into the generated APK.